# DirectoryEntry object "dispose" method stuck

Tags: c#, dispose, directoryentry

I found a big broblem in my code, while using `DirectoryEntry` object. When calling "Dispose" method, the program get stuck. Any idea what could cause this?

Here is the code:

```
foreach (DirectoryEntry oDireEntry in _DirectoryEntries)
{
     oDireEntry.Dispose();
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you define "stuck" a little better?  Is it throwing any exceptions? What sort of application is it?

Comment: Stuck as in "the debugger sits inside the Dispose method forever" or stuck as in "the entries do not get disposed"? In the second case, an exception may be thrown inside the loop that prevents your code from disposing all entries

Comment: "Stuck" means the 'dispose' call never ends.

Comment: It is a desktop application

Comment: I noticed something weird that probably has something to do with this bug: When debugging the code, and putting a break point on the "dispose" call, the evaluation of the DirectoryEntry object fails with a "Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation." message.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use **using** construction due initializing _DirectoryEntries list?
Pseudocode:

```
using (var _DirectoryEntries = new DirectoryEntries())
{
   // code to add items to list
   // anoy other work with list
}
```

So, this way you don't need to use your loop for elements to dispose it.

Regards.

Comment: It is not that simple, because I use the DirectoryEntry object as a member of a singleton class. I need to dispose it when I do a specific action which resets this singleton object.